# Selenium - Find specific Button in Table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i try to find a specific Button inside a Table (Webelement - Selenium), but the Button has no ID or something else. May some one can give me a hint how to do that?

In this example I want to "Click" the Delete Button by katja@katja.com
As Program I use VisualStudio.

The Table looks like this:

```
<tr id="0dca11a5-11d3-4ab5-a255-e55ab331dc19">
   <td class="emailAdress">max@max.com</td>
   <td class="action">
      <form action="RemoveUserFromAccount" method="post">
         <input id="usernameToRemove" name="usernameToRemove" value="max@max.com">
         <button type="submit" class="button button-danger remove_user">Delete</button>
      </form>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="e5b111b5-71e9-4272-bcd9-11c8fe831a49">
   <td class="emailAdress">john@john.com</td>
   <td class="action">
      <form action="RemoveUserFromAccount" method="post">
         <input id="usernameToRemove" name="usernameToRemove" value="john@john.com">
         <button type="submit" class="button button-danger remove_user">Delete</button>
      </form>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="a50d080c-6ed1-480f-b92f-6576fe3e6549">
   <td class="emailAdress">katja@katja.com</td>
   <td class="action">
      <form action="RemoveUserFromAccount" method="post">
         <input id="usernameToRemove" name="usernameToRemove" value="katja@katja.com">
         <button type="submit" class="button button-danger remove_user">Delete</button>
      </form>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks for any Help
Andy

I tried this codes, but it did not solve anything:

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[.='katja@katja.com']")
```

OR

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*contains(text(),'katja@katja.com')]")
```

OR

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//*[text() = 'katja@katja.com']"))
button.get_attribute('parentElement')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath selects the `<td>` element containing the email address `“katja@katja.com”`, then moves to the following sibling `<td>` containing the form, and finally selects the `<button>` element within that form.

```
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[text()='katja@katja.com']/following-sibling::td/form/button")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relationships in XPATH too. My solution:

```
del_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[text()="katja@katja.com"]/..//button')
```

Here, we find the element with the td with *text "katja@katja.com"*, take its parent element **(/..)**, then within that parent element inside 'somewhere', we find a button element **(//button)**. Since in the code you provided this is the only button element within the tr that contains both tds, the button can be directly identified like this.